# Typing using key combinations?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-10.04, accessibility

I'm a Ubuntu 10.04 user who is looking for a way to, for example, make my computer type a "+" character when I hold down the Windows Key (I think it's called "super" in Linux world) and press the "k" key. I need this to work in all applications. (I'm a person with a typing disability, and I need to adapt Ubuntu to my needs.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is likely to be closed (as it is not programming related) I will not go into great detail.  All the answers you need are [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.html#ss5.2) and [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: I reposted the question: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/typing-using-key-combinations-in-ubuntu-linux